# React.js and Firebase how to display data in my bootstraptable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, bootstrap-table

Hi guys i want to  create simple table in react with gets data from firebase, here is the code for table:

```
class Table1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BootstrapTable data={this.props.data}>
          <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id'>
          </TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name'>
          </TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='value'>
          </TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Table1;
```

it is just a simple table code that i found on a tutorial website, this is how i pass data to dable :

```
var data = [
  {name: "username"}
];
```

and

```
  render() {
    return (
      <body  className = "aa">
       <div>
        <div className = "bb">
         <Table1 data={data}/>
        </div>
       </div>
      </body>
    );
  }
```

and successfully it displays `"username"` in table, thats fine, but now i want to display all usernames from my firebase database, thats how i recieve it from firebase:

```
componentDidMount() {
    db.onceGetUsers().on("child_added", snap =>{
                var username = snap.child("name").child("name").val();
    })
  }
```

so.. here im stuck, because i totally have how to put this `var username` data in my table, I am new in web apps, not even talking about React.. so please, can someone help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Well.

Store the response from `firebase` into `state` and use it as you want

Like.

```
     constructor() {
      this.state = {
       responseFromFirebase: type of response....
      }
     }
     componentDidMount() {
        db.onceGetUsers().on("child_added", snap =>{
          var username = snap.child("name").child("name").val();

          this.setState({responseFromFirebase: username})
        })
      }
```

Then use `state` response like `this.state.responseFromFirebase`.

That's it. Easy!

Comment: What else do you want?

Comment: I want to display all usernames. There are, let say 3 users i want to display all 3 usernames in the table

Comment: Then get all users from firebase and `setState`, after that you can render it. I don't know about your structure in `firebase`

Comment: Well, i guess thats not the problem.. My problem for now is that there is only one cell where my app keep displaying usernames, and when im debbuging this, first in cell is displayed 1st username then 2nd and then 3rd, then debbuger ends its work and cell displays only one, last username that has been loaded, i guess that there is something wrong with my table, it needs to create individual cell for one username..